# Is there any freeware tool that can convert fractional values of various numeral systems to each other?

Tags: number-systems

I have already searched Google and I am finding no tool to convert fractional values of various numeral system into each other.

Can anyone hive me a hand?

I need a freeware executable for WindowsXP.

Comment: Which language? BTW, Javascript's `.toString` already supports base-N real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WolframAlpha](http://wolframalpha.com) can do it for you, e.g. the query `7/3 in base 5` converts it.

Without a specified operating system, finding tools is just guessing we're targeting the correct OS :).